What is the "Angular way" of managing multiple checkboxes in reactive forms?
I'm trying to figure out the best way to manage multiple checkboxes in Angular reactive forms. I want the checkbox value to be sent along, so not "on" or "true", which it seems I was getting when I first tried to set up these checkboxes how I thought Angular would want them.
I will have a lot of checkboxes, think like a doctor's office where you have to fill out any medical conditions. For the prototyping I'm doing I'm just using colors, so what I want to end up in the form model is something like:
Colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

I do have that working, but it seems overly involved and not really the "Angular way" because I'm doing things manually.
My template (using the translate pipe for internationalization):
{{ "step1.fields.colors.label" | translate }}
<ng-container *ngFor="let color of colors">
    <label>
        <input 
            type="checkbox"
            name="Colors"
            [value]="color"
            (change)="checkboxChange($event, 'Colors')">
        {{ "step1.fields.colors.options." + color | translate }}
    </label>
</ng-container>

You'll probably notice the (change) event handler instead of a formControlName directive.
The change handler, which basically just adds or removes a FormControl to the Colors array (in the form model):
checkboxChange(event: Event, formModelKey: string) {
    const isChecked = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).checked;
    const value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    const checkboxArray = <FormArray>this.form.get('step-1.' + formModelKey);

    if (isChecked) {
        checkboxArray.push(new FormControl(value));
    } else {
        let index = checkboxArray.controls.findIndex(checkbox => checkbox.value === value);
        checkboxArray.removeAt(index);
    }
}

This does work, but feels a little odd because it's being handled manually. which seems to defeat the purpose of a reactive system.
Another issue is when you navigate away, then come back to a checkbox page, the values in the Colors form model aren't restored/reflected in the UI like all the other form model values. So I have to restore those manually. Here's how I do that in my prototype, I call this on ngAfterViewInit.
populateSelectedCheckboxes() {
    if (this.selectedColors) {
        const checkboxArray = <FormArray>this.form.get('step-1.' + 'Colors');

        for (let control of checkboxArray.controls) {
            const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][name=Colors]');
            checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
                if ((checkbox as HTMLInputElement).value === control.value) {
                    checkbox.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
                }
            });
        }
    }
}


It seems like you have already a FormArray. Why are you building an additional structure around it? Can't you just directly iterate over the form array items?

Here is a 6 years old article, which is still useful. I think you will find all answers there... https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular

You could use a FormArray, which can have items added to it dynamically. In the template/html, you can simply loop over the FormArray and display a checkbox for each FormGroup of the FormArray elements.
form = this.formBuilder.group({
    colors: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    // All other controls added here aswell.
})

